# Multiple primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have this table with a composite primary key:

```
create table mercati(
ubicazione varchar(20) not null,
giorno ENUM('LU','MA','ME','GI','VE','SA','DO') not null,
ora_inizio time not null,
ora_fine time not null,
comune varchar(20) not null,
primary key(ubicazione,comune),
foreign key(comune) references comuni(comune)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then I execute

```
Insert into mercati values ("liberty square","LU",07:00,13:00,"Padova")
```

But when I try

```
Insert into mercati values ("Corso Australia","LU",07:00,13:00,"Padova")
```

it says "Duplicate entry 'Padova' for key 'comune'".
But comune alone isn't primary, or not?

Comment: Could you please post exact output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mercati` here?

Comment: Your query syntax is not even valid with the `.` and no quotes around the times

Comment: Your question probably doesn't reflect your code : see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8852/3

Comment: The output of show create table is:
mercati | CREATE TABLE `mercati` (
  `ubicazione` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `giorno` enum('LU','MA','ME','GI','VE','SA','DO') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `ora_inizio` time NOT NULL,
  `ora_fine` time NOT NULL,
  `comune` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ubicazione`,`comune`),
  UNIQUE KEY `comune` (`comune`),
  CONSTRAINT `mercati_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`comune`) REFERENCES `comuni` (`comune`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your table structure and add as primary key an integer column with auto_increment

```
create table mercati(
id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ubicazione varchar(20) not null,
    giorno ENUM('LU','MA','ME','GI','VE','SA','DO') not null,
    ora_inizio time not null,
    ora_fine time not null,
    comune varchar(20) not null,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(comune) references comuni(comune)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now you can insert data witout problems

```
Insert into mercati (ubicazione, giorno, ora_inizio, ora_fine, comune) values ("liberty square","LU",'07:00','13:00',"Padova");
Insert into mercati (ubicazione, giorno, ora_inizio, ora_fine, comune) values ("Corso Australia","LU",'07:00','13:00',"Padova") ;
```

#### [Live Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50830/2)

Comment: I thought about add an ID, but I prefer to avoid...By the way I'll adopt this solution, thank you